# Reference to underlying class instance

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Class1 in VBA-Excel with a Name-variable and a dynamically created Button, which is an instance of another class (cButton). I want to reference the Class1 instance in he click-event of the button, but I can't get it to work. Minimal working example:

Class1

```
Option Explicit
Dim myButton As cButton
Public ClassName As String

Sub createButton()
    Set myButton = New cButton
    Set myButton.ButtonObject = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "btn", True)
    myButton.ButtonName = "NiceButton"
End Sub
```

Class cButton

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents ButtonObject As MSForms.CommandButton
Public ButtonName As String

Private Sub ButtonObject_Click()
    MsgBox ("This Button is called " & Me.ButtonName)
    'MsgBox ("This Button belongs to " & Me.Me.ClassName) 'Compile Error: Method or Data Member not found
End Sub
```

I create an instance and click the button in the Userform1:

```
Option Explicit
Dim myClass As Class1

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set myClass = New Class1
    myClass.ClassName = "NiceClass"
    myClass.createButton
End Sub
```

When I click the button it displays the Button-Name correctly (via Me.Name in ButtonObject_Click), but I did not manage to reference the underlying class instance to display the name of the class as well. (I know, Me.Me.ClassName was a bit naive, but I couldn't find a solution anywhere). How can I reference the class instance of Class1 (myClass) to which the button belongs?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can add a "Parent" reference in cButton and set it in createButton.

Comment: Cool, that's an easy solution. Thanks. Just to be sure: "Set myButton.ParentClass = Me" in createButton() sets an actual reference to the parent class and does not create a copy, right? So when I change the original class I can still reference it via the button? And just out of curiosity: Is there a "native" way to reference the original class instance without explicitly creating the reference in cButton?

Comment: Yes, no copy is done, and no "native" way AFAIK, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Can I somehow mark that my question has been answered and that Vincent's solution works just fine?